# Websocket evnt.data undefined after refresh

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, refresh, undefined

I am using websocket for showing real time message updates from the server.

My server code snippet is :
My server keeps sending string to my client till the connection is open.

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, @PathParam("client-id") String clientId) {

    for (Session client : clients) {
        while (client.isOpen()) {
            client.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(getStatus());

        }
    }

}

@OnClose
void onClose(Session peer) {
    System.out.println("Removed Peers");
    clients.remove(peer);
}
```

The `getStatus()` function returns a comma separated string.

My client receives the string(comma separated string) and keeps calling `setData()` which sets the html element the value of this string.

My client side code is :

```
var websocket;
var rows;
var vM;
function connect() {

    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        webSocket = new MozWebSocket(URL);
    } else {
        webSocket = new WebSocket(URL);
    }
    websocket.onopen = function(evnt) {
        onOpen(evnt);
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evnt) {
        onMessage(evnt);
    };
    websocket.onerror = function(evnt) {
        onError(evnt);
    };
    websocket.onclose = function() {
        console.log("Disconnected");
    };

    displayMigration();    

}

function onOpen(evnt) {

  setInterval(function() {
    if (websocket.bufferedAmount === 0) {      
        websocket.send("connect");
    }
 }, 600);

}
function onMessage(evnt) {

if (typeof evnt.data === "string") {
    setData(evnt);
    startDataUpdation();
    console.log(evnt.data);
   }
}
function onError(evnt) {
    alert('ERROR: ' + evnt.data);
}
}
```

Now my websocket executes as required till the time i refresh the screen.Once I refresh it the evnt.data is undefined so onMessage is not getting called even if the connection is open and in readyState=1.

Same behavior is reflected across different browsers. I am using `glassfish server 4.0` in `Netbeans 7.4 j2ee`.

Also after refresh I get this error in the console:
The connection to `ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketWorking_2/websocket/client-id` was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: Why do you have a while inside the for loop. This is basically going to stay looping while the client connection is open and is not going to go iterate to the other clients unless the current the first client connection gets close.

Comment: the getStatus() function returns different status each time so the string must get updated everytime. Hence I have used the while loop.